# Punkt am Ende eines Satzes, der in einer Klammer steht

Tags: punctuation

Ich habe eine Frage zur Zeichensetzung, welche eh nicht meine Stärke ist.

Nehmen wir mal folgenden Beispielsatz:

> Das ist das Leben des kleinen Brian (Ist das ein schöner Name? Eigentlich wollten wir einen anderen.).

Der Text in der Klammer bezieht sich nur auf "Brian" und nicht auf den ganzen Satz, wenn ich das richtig verstanden habe, dann ist es somit schon einmal richtig, dass der eingeklammerte Teil vor dem Punkt kommt. In der Klammer steht allerdings auch ein kompletter Satz, der dann ja auch mit einem Punkt endet.

Wäre der Beispielsatz dann korrekt? Endet es mit ".)."?

Comment: Für die an der quasi [englischen Version](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6632/where-does-the-period-go-when-using-parentheses) der Frage Interessierende.

Comment: Deine Prämisse möchte ich infrage stellen. Im eigentlichen Satz ist Brian eine Person, in der Klammer geht es um ein Wort. Bei "Das ist das Leben des kleinen Brian (Hat er einen schönen Namen? ..." würde ich aber zustimmen. "(Ist Brian ein schöner Name? ..." wäre eine alternative Fortsetzung. Den Kerninhalt der Frage tangiert das aber nur peripher.

Answer (score 11):

1. Allein schon, weil es vollständige Sätze sind – die eigentlich auch außerhalb der Klammern stehen könnten –, finde ich es sinnvoll, den Teil **hinter** den Punkt zu stellen und somit als **eigenständige Texteinheit** zu betrachten.

   > Das ist das Leben des kleinen Brian. (Ist das ein schöner Name? Eigentlich wollten wir einen anderen.)
2. Wenn du unbedingt den Teil innerhalb schreiben möchtest, dann ist es korrekt den Satz mit ")." zu beenden, denn...

   > [§88](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf86-88.html#pgf88): Ist der Zusatz oder Nachtrag in einen anderen Satz einbezogen, so lässt man seinen Schlusspunkt weg

   Nur wenn der Satz eine eigenständige Texteinheit ist, wie eingangs in Punkt 1 erwähnt, wird der Schlusspunkt gesetzt. Denn im gerade zitierten Paragraphen heißt es weiter:

   > wird er als Ganzsatz oder als selbständige Texteinheit verstanden, so setzt man den Schlusspunkt.

   Ausrufe- und Fragezeichen werden jedoch immer gesetzt. Neben der oben gegebenen Variante 1, steht einem also auch folgendes frei:

   > Das ist das Leben des kleinen Brian (Ist das ein schöner Name? Eigentlich wollten wir einen anderen).

Schöner ist aber definitiv Variante 1.

Comment: Danke für den Link, allerdings steht dann ja direkt dahinter: "wird er als Ganzsatz oder als selbständige Texteinheit verstanden, so setzt man den Schlusspunkt." - Jetzt ist mein Beispiel ja eigentlich ein Ganzsatz (oder man könnte einen daraus machen)!?

Comment: @Feroc Damit ist Fall 1 wieder gemeint (bezieht sich auf den vorherigen Paragraph, den splattne zitiert). Beispiel 3 und 4 "Damit wäre dieses Thema ..." nehmen hierauf Bezug. Einmal steht der ganze Ausdruck vor dem Punkt, einmal dahinter.

Comment: Tut mir leid, verstehe ich nicht. Beispiel 3 und 4 beziehen sich ja leider wieder nicht auf ein einzelnes Wort, sondern sind ein Nachtrag zum kompletten Satz. Aber gut, kommen meinem Beispiel wohl am nächsten. Ich finde es halt seltsam, dass ich dann 3 Sätze in die Klammer schreibe und der letzte keinen Punkt bekommt.

Comment: @Feroc Jetzt hast du mich abgehängt. Es ist aber egal, ob du dich auf ein Wort oder ganzen Satz hier beziehst. Wenn du es direkt hinter das Wort schreiben willst, weil du den Bezug explizit dadurch hervorben willst, dann musst du Variante 1 nehmen und somit den inneren Punkt droppen. Es ist aber dennoch kein Problem, das ganze dahinter zu schieben. Der Bezug ist immer noch klar.

Answer (score 4):

Im [amtlichen Regelwerk zur deutschen Rechtschreibung](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/regelwerk.html) gibt es folgenden Paragraphen:

> **§ 87** Mit Klammern kann man neben einzelnen Ganzsätzen insbesondere auch größere Textteile einschließen und auf diese Weise als selbständige Texteinheit kennzeichnen.

mit dem Beispiel

> Sie betonte, dass sie für den Erfolg garantieren könne. (Ich weiß es noch ganz genau, da ich mir das notiert hatte. Und ich habe ihr diese Notiz auch gezeigt.) Aber heute will sie nichts mehr davon wissen.

Aus dem Beispiel wird ersichtlich, dass der Satz vor der Klammer mit einem Punkt abgeschlossen wird und bei der schließenden Klammer nur ein Punkt verwendet wird.

Comment: Allerdings bezieht sich der Satz in der Klammer auf den kompletten Satz davor, während sich in meinem Beispiel der Satz in der Klammer nur auf das eine Wort bezieht, das halt zufällig am Ende des Satzes steht. Man könnte das Beispiel auch umformen, z.B. in "... Brian ([langer Satz].), der...". Da hätte man dann ",).", sieht ähnlich seltsam aus.

Comment: @Feroc "Des kleinen Brians Leben schauen wir uns einmal an. (Ist das überhaupt ein schöner Name? Wir wollten eigentlich einen anderen." -- Wie du siehst, muss die Klammer nicht unmittelbar nach dem Begriff folgen. Es reicht, wenn du am Ende des Satzes Bezug nimmst.

Comment: @Em1 Natürlich kann man Sätze immer so umstellen, dass der Bezug dann geändert wird. Mir geht es aber ja gerade darum, dass sich die Klammer nur auf einen einzelnen Begriff bezieht und dieser Begriff direkt vor einem Satzzeichen steht.